# how to delete a folder using invoke command in powershell

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

First time asking a question here after using it for a long time.

I'm currently making a powershell script to delete userdata when they left the company for a month.

I already tried deleting the folder using the normal remove-item and this works however this is a very slow process when going over the network.

I then found out about the invoke-command function which can run on a remote computer.
Now i can't seem to get this working.

I keep getting the error that the path is not found.
However it seems like powershell is changing my path.
How can i prevent this from happening?

```
Cannot find path 'C:\Users\admcia\Documents\P$\PERSONAL\JOBA' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\admcia...$\PERSONAL\JOBA:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ODNDATA
```

my code is the following:
Note that P$ is the local drive letter on the server.
Also note That $item.SamAccountName is used for creating foldername. (we use Samaccountname as the name of the users folder.

```
     $localPath1 = "P$" + "\PERSONAL\" + $item.SamAccountName
     $serverName = "Remotecompter"
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { Remove-Item $using:localPath1 -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false }
```

Comment: @olaf the p$ is hardcoded text as that is the driver letter.

Comment: @Olaf it is the local drive letter on the remote server. the data is on the p-drive of remotecomputer

Comment: If this is a local path why do you use a dollar sign? It should be `P:` when you access a local drive. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If as seen from your local machine, the drive is `\\Remotecomputer\P$\`, then for the remote computer (where the code is executed) the path is just `P:\`.
To combine strings into a path, I would suggest you better use the Join-Path cmdlet rather than concatenating the strings with '+'

Try

```
$localPath1 = Join-Path -Path 'P:\PERSONAL' -ChildPath $item.SamAccountName
$serverName = "Remotecompter"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { Remove-Item $using:localPath1 -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use -ArgumentList in Invoke command,

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock { 
param($localPath1)
Remove-Item $localPath1 -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
 } -ArgumentList($localPath1)
```

make sure your path is correct, and if it does not work try to hardcode the path in your code.

Comment: Hi,
I tried this but it did not work.
It keeps giving the same result. 
It should not create the c:\ part. and go straight to the p-drive.